# How do I convert a named list to an array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, iteration, jq

I have some data that looks like this

```
{
    "type1": [
      "a", "b"
    ],
    "type2": [
      "c", "d"
    ],
    "type3": "x"
}
```

And I would like to convert it into

```
[
    {"value": "a", "type": "type1" },
    {"value": "b", "type": "type1" },
    {"value": "c", "type": "type2" },
    {"value": "d", "type": "type2" },
    {"value": "x", "type": "type3" },
]
```

The array elements can have one or more values. Is this possible using jq?

I was able to handle the non-array elements but my expression retains only the last item in the list.

```
to_entries 
  | map_values({value:[.value]|flatten, type:.key})
  | map_values({value:.value[], type:.type})
```

I get this result where elements "b" and "d" are excluded from the result.

```
[
  {
    "value": "a",
    "type": "type1"
  },
  {
    "value": "c",
    "type": "type2"
  },
  {
    "value": "x",
    "type": "type3"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use the various type filters with alternation to make it more compact. Assuming you would only have to deal with values of arrays or scalars, I would write it this way:

```
[to_entries[] | {value:(.value | arrays[] // .), type:.key}]
```

https://jqplay.org/s/1jCG6soXuG

Don't underestimate the usefulness of expressions that can generate multiple values, it can make your filters less complicated when used effectively.

Comment: Wow! Short and neat.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this using the following approach

- Convert items to key-value pair
- Convert values to arrays and flatten
- Map each item

  - store type in variable
  - map each value in array, adding the type attribute
  - flatten nested array

```
to_entries 
  | map_values({value:[.value]|flatten, type:.key}) 
  | map( .type as $type | .value | map({type:$type, value: .}))
  |flatten
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/iyHTZ_KzzE)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient, concise and perhaps "canonical" solution:

```
[to_entries[]
 | (if .value|type == "array" then {value: .value[]} else {value} end)
   + {type: .key} ]
```

Or equivalently, if you prefer using `map`:

```
to_entries
| map( (if .value|type == "array" then {value: .value[]} 
        else {value}
        end)
      + {type: .key} )
```

The subtlety here is that `{value: .value[]}` expands to a stream of JSON objects, as if by: `.value[] | {value: .}`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, I see that this works even when the values are objects.

Comment: Yes, that's the point of jq - generality without complications!

Answer (score 0):

I put your data in d.json, and put this in d.jq:

```
# vim: tabstop=2 expandtab shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
[ 
  .
  |to_entries[]
  |.key as $k
  |(
    (.value|strings|{"type":($k),"value":.}),
    (.value|arrays|reduce .[] as $i ( [];  . += [ { "type": ($k), "value":  $i } ] ) )[]
  )
]
```

Then ran jq with

```
jq -f d.jq d.json
```

I know there must be a better way :-)
But you end up with:

```
[
  {
    "type": "type1",
    "value": "a"
  },
  {
    "type": "type1",
    "value": "b"
  },
  {
    "type": "type2",
    "value": "c"
  },
  {
    "type": "type2",
    "value": "d"
  },
  {
    "type": "type3",
    "value": "x"
  }
]
```

Comment: `jq "$(cat d.jq)" d.json` should be changed to `jq -f d.jq d.json`.

Comment: Thanks. If I remove the `|strings` it works for objects also.